# gvim doesn't display characters correctly

Tags: vim, character-encoding

That's how it looks like when I start gvim:

[image]

When I start typing, black versions of these symbols appear. It looks like gvim simply replaces every character with these strange symbols.

Vim works fine though.

I'm using gvim 7.4 on arch linux.

The problem might have started to occur after I tried to use gvim as my external editor for sylpheed. I'm not sure about this though, gvim might have never worked on my system yet.

I used dropbox because I can't post images on stackoverflow.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Yesterday I updated my system and the problem disappeard.

Comment: I'm having this same issue with a brand new system.